# Qt Creator Stuck in "Launching Debugger" on Mac os

Tags: macos, qt, qt-creator

I'm trying to debug my application on Mac OS X 10.11.6, using Qt 5.3.2.

The debugging progress stops on "Launching debugger" and there's a message on debug mode saying: Starting debugger "LldbEngine" for ABI "x86-macos-generic-mach_o-64bit"...

What do I need to do for the debugger to work?

Comment: Qt version is one thing - what you really care about is the version of Qt Creator, which is the IDE you're using (a separate product from Qt itself). You most likely need to update to the most recent version of Qt Creator. Note that Qt Creator supports multiple Qt versions and you don't need to upgrade your presumably commercial Qt just because you use a newer IDE. Usually you'd want to use the newest Qt Creator at all times.

Comment: I had a similar issue,
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Resources/Python/lldb/__init__.py` was crashing.
I resolved it by uninstalling the python@2 with brew..

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and also related to Python apparently.

Following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56711596/1548052):

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.lldb DefaultPythonVersion 2
```

immediately solved the issue for me.

Also found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58053946/1548052) pointing to a Qt Creator issue:
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-22955

Answer (score 1):

macOS 10.13.1 / Qt 5.9 / Qt Creator 4.3.1 / Xcode9.1
I am using macports 2.5.3. The problem was indeed related to python.

```
sudo port select --set python python27-apple
```

did the trick for me.