# Qt Debugger using wrong python version on mac

Tags: python, c++, macos, qt

I'm on macOS Mojave 10.14.6. My Qt version is 5.13.1. My Qt Creator version is 4.10.0.

When I set a breakpoint and run the application, the debugger never finishes and prints to the debugger log with the below error.

So, the wrong version of python for lldb is being used, from what I can gather. Is this a Qt Creator setting or a mac setting and how can I fix it?

> dCALL: SETUP ENGINE
>   dSTARTING LLDB: /usr/bin/lldb
>    Setting up inferior...
>   <1loadDumpers({"token":1})
>   <2executeDebuggerCommand({"command":"settings append target.source-map /Users/qt/work/qt /usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.13.1/../Src","token":2})
>   <3setupInferior({"attachpid":0,"breakonmain":0,,"executable":"/Users/kyle/GoogleDrive/programming/MasteringQt5/Chapter02/build-Sysinfo-Desktop-Debug/Sysinfo.app/Contents/MacOS/Sysinfo","nativemixed":0,"platform":"","processargs":"","remotechannel":"","startmode":1,"sysroot":"","token":3,"useterminal":0,"workingdirectory":"/Users/kyle/GoogleDrive/programming/MasteringQt5/Chapter02/build-Sysinfo-Desktop-Debug/Sysinfo.app/Contents/MacOS"})
>
> (lldb) script sys.path.insert(1, '/Applications/Qt Creator.app/Contents/Resources/debugger/')
>
> (lldb) script from lldbbridge import *
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "", line 1, in 
>    File "/Applications/Qt Creator.app/Contents/Resources/debugger/lldbbridge.py", line 1912
>      print message
>                  ^
>
> SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(message)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a quick fix, run this in terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.lldb DefaultPythonVersion 2
```

The problem is the lldb's default version is now Python 3. This is causing some issues with Qt that will hopefully get resolved soon:

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-22955

Comment: Updating Qt Creator to 4.10.1 does indeed fix this: https://www.qt.io/blog/qt-creator-4.10.1-released

Answer (score 0):

This is addressed in [QTCREATORBUG-22955](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-22955) and fixed in [Qt Creator 4.10.1](https://www.qt.io/blog/qt-creator-4.10.1-released).